# Why is a "geography" type needed at all in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geography-data-type

Let `a` and `b` be two points. `ST_Distance(a, b)` returns their distance.

Instead of having two data types, geometry and geography, that practically overload the meaning of `ST_Distance()`, we could instead have a single type (a pair of WGS84 co-ordinates) and two functions, `ST_CartesianDistance()` and `ST_DistanceOnSphere()`. To me (at this stage of my understanding of GIS) this would make more sense, because if I have a point `POINT(23.0 38.0)`, then that fully defines it; when I want to make an operation on it, I can decide what kind of operation I want. Whether I want a calculation on a sphere or a calculation on a plane, the point is still `POINT(23.0 38.0)`.

1. Why did the designers of PostGIS (or whichever standard is behind it) choose to do it like they did?
2. Does `Geography`'s internal storage differ from `Geometry`'s with srid=4326? Why?

Comment: @TomazicM I don't really like the new title you gave. How about this: "Does the PostGIS geography type do anything else than overload the PostGIS functions?"

Comment: But maybe this new attempt at a title is a bit too smart :-)   Damn, it's a simple question really, how can it be so hard to summarize it?

Comment: If you don't like it, simply change it back or to whatever you want. Title is meant to attract potentional answerer with the gist of the question (like newspaper titles). Short titles make easier to quickly browse through tons of new questions.

Comment: In short, the developers most likely proceeded from the fact that the type of geometry is necessary for calculations in the flat- rectangular coordinate system, and the type of geography for calculations on the globe and on ellipsoids, for example, to calculate the length of a large circle (orthodromy), etc. ... and the correct answer can provide us with the developers themselves :-), they go to this site...

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 3):

The Paragraph 4.2.2 in PostGIS [manual](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography), I think it describes the reasoning behind your first q:

> The geography type allows you to store data in longitude/latitude
>   coordinates, but at a cost: there are fewer functions defined on
>   GEOGRAPHY than there are on GEOMETRY; those functions that are defined
>   take more CPU time to execute.
>
> The type you choose should be conditioned on the expected working area
>   of the application you are building. Will your data span the globe or
>   a large continental area, or is it local to a state, county or
>   municipality?
>
> - If your data is contained in a small area, you might find that
>     choosing an appropriate projection and using GEOMETRY is the best
>     solution, in terms of performance and functionality available.
> - If your data is global or covers a continental region, you may find
>     that GEOGRAPHY allows you to build a system without having to worry
>     about projection details. You store your data in longitude/latitude,
>     and use the functions that have been defined on GEOGRAPHY.
> - If you don't understand projections, and you don't want to learn about
>     them, and you're prepared to accept the limitations in functionality
>     available in GEOGRAPHY, then it might be easier for you to use
>     GEOGRAPHY than GEOMETRY. Simply load your data up as
>     longitude/latitude and go from there.

For your second question, again from the manual:

> The basis for the PostGIS geographic type is a sphere. The shortest
>   path between two points on the sphere is a great circle arc. That
>   means that calculations on geographies (areas, distances, lengths,
>   intersections, etc) must be calculated on the sphere, using more
>   complicated mathematics. For more accurate measurements, the
>   calculations must take the actual spheroidal shape of the world into
>   account.

That spheroidal shape, the most widely known spheroid (eg WGS84) or **not** (eg. a[ny in this random list i've found](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.spatial.doc/ids_spat_270.htm)) or even you could define your own (eg. The moon, or Mars)

And internally, yes it is a different data type, which can be seen in my view as an extension of the geometry dt.